# Honeycomb Recent App Automatic Screenshot Cache

Tags: android, graphics, android-3.0-honeycomb

In Android 3.0, there are automatic screenshots taken of applications for use in the "Recent Apps" list. It looks like SurfaceFlinger is responsible for taking these screenshots based on the following log output:

```
D/SurfaceFlinger(  133): screenshot: sw=216, sh=135, minZ=0, maxZ=21020
D/SurfaceFlinger(  133): screenshot: result = OK
```

Where (if at all) on the filesystem are these images cached? iOS has a similar feature where screenshots are automatically taken when an application is sent to the background, and the images are cached in /private/var/root/Library/Caches/Snapshots, and I'd like to know if Android also keeps these images somewhere accessible.

Answer (score 1):

These thumbnails are not accessible by applications.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified - I meant accessible by anyone with access to the file system (adb shell), not necessarily to be used by any application. I'm curious in seeing where/how they're stored.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void getRecentTaskThumbnails() {
    if (mBitmaps != null) {
        mBitmaps.clear();
    } else {
        mBitmaps = new LinkedList<Bitmap>();
    }
    mCurIndex = 0;

    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo> recentTasks = am.getRecentTasks(
            20, ActivityManager.RECENT_IGNORE_UNAVAILABLE);
    for (ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo task : recentTasks) {
        Log.e(TAG, "task:"
                + task.baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName() + "="
                + task.persistentId);

        ActivityManager.TaskThumbnails thumbs = am
                .getTaskThumbnails(task.persistentId);
        if(thumbs != null && thumbs.mainThumbnail != null) {
            mBitmaps.add(thumbs.mainThumbnail);
            Log.e(TAG, "thumbs=" + thumbs + "size="+thumbs.mainThumbnail.getWidth()+","+thumbs.mainThumbnail.getHeight());              
        }
    }
}
```